# Как уменьшить размер шрифта в Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

Можно ли уменьшить размер шрифта в *Android Studio*?

Больно уж неудобно ползать по классам, когда они по *300+* строк кода, а на экран вмещается всего лишь *50* !

Answer (score 14, accepted):

можно. это в **File > Settings**

1. Editor > General > Change font size (Zoom) with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Mouse Wheel</kbd> - галочку нужно поставить
2. Editor > Color & Fonts > Font > Size : *14*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо, через 7 минут приму ответ. Сайт ругается.

Comment: Стоит заметить, что для дефолтных тем нельзя изменить размер шрифта в настройках. Предварительно нужно создать собственную тему - копию дефолтной, нажав на кнопку *Save As ..* и уже в ней менять шрифт и все, что угодно.

Comment: @pavlofff согласень ! Тут на рисунке это указано. Спасибо

Comment: Да, заработало! Только установленный по умолчанию шрифт вручную всё равно не меняется, зато теперь таки заработал Ctrl+мышка и решила мою проблему. Не понятно, зачем сделали это разрешение на изменение шрифта, будто в AS проблем нет. Издевательство над организмом.

Answer (score 2):

попробуйте поскролить с нажатой клавишей Ctrl. Или же измените в настройках студии. Там в настройках редактора если не ошибаюсь должны быть настройки шрифта.

Comment: C `Ctrl` вариант не работает.

Comment: что бы `Ctrl` работал нужно галочку поставить

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, скажите, почему Вы постоянно на сайте находитесь?) Меня это уже пугает! :D

Comment: @bukashka101, всё просто - я мультовод наоборот - под моим акком судит толпа русскоговорящих индусов. По одному на каждый часовой пояс планеты)

Comment: @bukashka занятная система ;)